# Return and print giving different outputs in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, return

I'm trying to merge two arrays and return the sorted array (#88 on leetcode) and this the code I used:

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        if (m > 0 and n > 0):
            merged = nums1[0:m] + nums2[0:n]
            result = sorted(merged)
            print(result)
            return result
```

Input is

```
[1,2,3,0,0,0,0]
3
[2,5,6]
3
```

Output is like this - 
[image]

Can someone please explain why print and return are giving different outputs?

Comment: Where are you running that code? I get `[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]` as both stdout and result when running locally.

Comment: Also, why are you expecting a `0` in the output?

Comment: is `List` a custom class? because if I were to try and use your code: `NameError: name 'List' is not defined`

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak my guess is that the question expects the merging and sorting to be done in place in the first list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/) and choosing python3 as the language, we are greeted with the following stub:

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """
```

Note the comment - the testing framework is looking at the state of nums1 and not the value you return - in fact, the specification is to NOT return anything.

You're printing out the return variable, which is, indeed, what you return.  But the variable actually used for the purposes of this question is not the return value of this function.

Reading the specification, in whatever format it is presented is always a good first step to take before writing anything.